# using toggle next in foreach not below the click

Tags: jquery, toggle

i'm trying to use toggle in my foreach , it's working if i put the div below .region but i want to put it after the class nameregion.

```
foreach($data as $plus) {
    echo '<a href="#" class="region"><img src="images/plus.png" style="float: left; margin-top:-5px; margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 5px;"></a>
    <div class="mytoggle">toggle contenu</div>
    <div style="color: #000; font-size: 20px; margin-bottom: 30px; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 0px; text-align: left;" class="nameregion">'.$plus['FRN_RGN_VALUE'].'</div>';
}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".mytoggle").hide();
$('.region').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.mytoggle').toggle('fast');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then it is not the next sibling, it is the next next sibling

```
$(".mytoggle").hide();
$('.region').click(function(){
    $(this).next().next('.mytoggle').toggle('fast');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/36JxB/)

Comment: Perfect i didn't know that we could use several next , thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.nextAll(:first)` for this

```
$(".mytoggle").hide();
$('.region').click(function(){
     $(this).nextAll('.mytoggle:first').toggle('fast');
});
```